# body in 301 http response

Tags: java, http, servlets

I have to send 301 response code.Below is the code I am using :

```
        resp.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        out.println(origReqBody);
        resp.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
        resp.setHeader("Location", homeSiteRedirUrl);
```

here i have observed that if "origReqBody" is blank then it is sending 301 and if it "origReqBody" is having some string then code is sending 302.In case of 302 i can see that Location Header is visible in the response 4 times.

Need to understand this behavior. I need to send body in 301.Is it possible.

Edit : 
After making setHeader and setStatus above println...

[image]

message 7 and 11 : If "origReqBody" is blank
message 27, 31 : If "origReqBody" is not blank

Same behaviour...i was expecting 301 instead of 302

Comment: Weird. I'm unable to reproduce it. If I put the location header (last line of your code), it's like I never printed anything to `out`. If I don't put the location then it prints. Either way, my servlet returns a `301`.

Comment: What version of servlet are you using? What's the container? Put a `System.out.println("status: "+response.getStatus());` at the beginning and at the end of the method, what do they print?

Comment: using servlet 2.5 and getStatus is not available.Container ( ie apache ) i am using is embedded in some proprietary software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PrintWriter` actually writes to output stream if there's content, which requires it to go ahead and serialize the headers and status code, since they come first in the response. So it's just ignoring subsequent calls to `setStatus` and `setHeader`. Just move those calls above the `println` and I bet it'll work as you expect.

Comment: What servlet container are you using?

Comment: using servlet 2.5 and getStatus is not available.Container ( ie apache ) i am using is embedded in some proprietary software

Comment: @ Isaac : Its working.There was some business logic issue ie if body is coming do sendRedirect.  ThanksYou were correct  :)